# Ajax return value as a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new in ajax, and i want to create ajax to return  value as a PHP variable,  i'm stuck trying to get the value from an ajax. I have the following form (view):

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="date_analysis[]" id="date_analysis" class="date_analysis input-group date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" size="12" value="<?php $a=set_value('date_analysis[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sulfur_ws[]" class="sulfur_ws" id="sulfur_ws" size="10" onkeyup="getValues()" value="<?php $a=set_value('sulfur_ws[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sulfur_vnaoh[]" class="sulfur_vnaoh" id="sulfur_vnaoh" size="10" onkeyup="getValues()" value="<?php $a=set_value('sulfur_vnaoh[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>    
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sulfur_total[]" class="sulfur_total" id="sulfur_total" size="10" onkeyup="getValues()" value="<?php $a=set_value('sulfur_total[0]'); echo $a; ?>"/></td>
```

Display:

[image]

Total field should be fillin automatically by formula: **sulfur_vnaoh * aVariable * 32.03* 1000 / sulfur_ws**

**aVariable** is a value from ajax (the value is different for each date analys). Here is my code :

Model Function:

```
function getdata_naoh($datetest){
    $result = $this->db1->query("select round(avg(cast(t_dtl.hasil_m as decimal(6,4))),4) as hasil_m from t_hdr JOIN  t_dtl ON t_hdr.headerid = t_dtl.headerid where id_solvent ='NaOH' AND status='ok' AND concentrate='0.0100' AND date_start <='$datetest' AND date_finish >='$datetest'");
    if($result->num_rows()>0){
        return $result->result_array();
    }else{
        return array();
    }
}
```

Controller Function:

```
function get_NaOH(){
    $date_analysis = trim($this->input->post('date_analysis'));
    $datetest = trim($this->input->post('date_analysis'));
    $datetest = substr($datetest,6,4).'-'.substr($datetest,3,2).'-'.substr($datetest,0,2);

    $dtnaoh = $this->M_tambahan->getdata_naoh($datetest);

    foreach($dtnaoh as $row){
        $data1 .= $row[hasil_m];
    }

    $data =  $data1;
    echo $data;
}
```

and View javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValues() {
        var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  

        for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_vnaoh[]") { 
              var dt_sulfur_vnaoh = obj[i].value;
          };
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_ws[]") { 
              var dt_sulfur_ws = obj[i].value
          };
          if (obj[i].name == "sulfur_hasil[]") {
            if ((dt_sulfur_ws != '')&&(dt_sulfur_vnaoh != '')) {


              var totalSulfur = ((eval(dt_sulfur_vnaoh))*aVariable*32.03*1000/(eval(dt_sulfur_ws))).toFixed(2);
              obj[i].value = totalSulfur;
            } else {
                obj[i].value = '';
            };
          };
        }
    };
</script>
```

// ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){         

        $(document).on('change', function() {
            var that = $(this);
            console.log(that.next());
            var col_date_analysis =  that.parent().prev().find('.date_analysis');
            var date_analysis = col_date_analysis.val();

            $.ajax({
                      type :"post",
                      url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/additionals/file/C_utils/get_NaOH",
                      data : { date_analysis: date_analysis },
                      success: function(data){
                          // code here
                      }
                  });
          });
        });

</script>
```

If i run the model query, it will give result value like below image:

[image]

I want that value to become a variable **aVariable** to complete the formula.

Any help would be appreciated greatly, thanks.

Comment: `$(document).on('change'` .... you haven't provided a target selector... change what?

Comment: Is there more than one row of inputs?

Comment: @charlietfl `$(document).on('change', '.date_analys', function() {`

Comment: @DFriend yes, i have more than one row inputs

Comment: OK..so the echo in php will be `data` in your success handler. Process whatever you need to do there

Comment: @charlietfl  I tried to select date analysis (success handler still empty) then i got ajax error `.../index.php/additionals/file/C_utils/get_NaOH  [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 90ms]`. Should i complete the success handler first before select the date field?

Comment: Ajax won't succeed if a 500 status is returned. Need to fix the php error first

Comment: @charlietfl `url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/additionals/file/C_utils/get_NaOH",` is wrong code ? the php tag ?

Comment: @metaphor, is `get_NaOH()` in a controller? The URL makes me believe it is not. It probably should be

Comment: @metaphor, It would be useful to see how you are constructing the initial view of the table. I imagine you are using a loop to build each row. Correct? Please edit the answer and show that code.

Comment: @charlietfl i was solved the ajax problem, there is no error anymore but i still don't know how to complete the formula: `var totalSulfur = ((eval(dt_sulfur_vnaoh))*aVariable*32.03*1000/(eval(dt_sulfur_ws))).toFixed(2);` i mean to fill the **aVariable**, this variable should be a value from **hasil_m** table column